# Animated texture that depends on camera perspective

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, texturing, uv

I am making an animation where the camera moves around. I would like the texture of the object stay normal to the camera's view for each frame. (ie. equivalent to selecting "project from view" on each frame and then rendering each frame independently)

Please see the picture below for an example. There could be 1000s of frames so I don't want to be making a huge "baked texture" file.

What is the simplest way to do this?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Using WINDOW TEXTURE COORDINATE

Use a ***Window*** *texture coordinate* for mapping. Adjust *Location*, *Rotation* and *Scale* parameters of the *Mapping* node to make the texture fit the object borders.
[image]
[image]

---

### Using UV PROJECT MODIFIER

Subdivide your *cube* a few times and unwrap it (I've marked seams and then unwrapped).
[image]

Add the ***UV Project Modifier***. Set up your *image texture*, set the *Camera* as a projector. If the image doesn't display correctly adjust the *Aspect* values.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why is your second animation so much smoother?

Comment: Because it has been rendered.

Comment: @PaulGonet - Do you know if it's possible to bake this projection?

Comment: @Neil Yes, in a way. There is projection paint, which works like the modifier except you unwrap the mesh from a certain angle and then use the project paint brush in texture paint mode.